# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I tried it but it was an error

> Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array

Does anyone have a solution for this ???

Hope someone could help , best regards :)

**MailController.php**

```
public function sendemail(Request $get)
{
    $this->validate($get,[
        "email"=>"required",
        "nis"=>"required",
        "nama"=>"required",
        "alamat_sekolah"=>"required",
        "judul"=>"required",
        "pesan"=>"required",
    ]);

    $email = $get->email;
    $nis = $get->nis;
    $nama = $get->nama;
    $alamat_sekolah = $get->alamat_sekolah;
    $judul = $get->judul;
    $pesan = $get->pesan;
    $pdf = $get->pdf;

    // $attachment = Student::findOrFail($get->id);
    // $storagePath = Storage::url($attachment->attachmentPath);

    Session::flash("success");
    Mail::to($email)->send( new SendEmail($nis,$nama,$alamat_sekolah,$judul,$pesan,$pdf));
    return back();
}
```

And this is my **SendEmail.php** file

```
    public function __construct($nis,$nama,$alamat_sekolah,$judul,$pesan,$pdf=[])
{

    set_time_limit(8000000);

    $this->ni = $nis;
    $this->nam = $nama;
    $this->alamat_seko = $alamat_sekolah;
    $this->jud = $judul;
    $this->pes = $pesan;
    $this->pdf = $pdf;
    //$this->attachmentFile = public_path() . '/' . $storagePath;
}

public function build()
{
    $e_nis = $this->ni;
    $e_nama = $this->nam;
    $e_alamat_sekolah = $this->alamat_seko;
    $e_judul = $this->jud;
    $e_pesan = $this->pes;
    return $this
    ->view('permohonan.template_mail', compact("e_pesan"))
    ->subject($e_judul)
    ->attach($this->pdf['pdf']->getRealPath(),
    [
        'as' => $this->pdf['pdf']->getClientOriginalName(),
        'mime' => $this->pdf['pdf']->getClientMimeType(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please show us the form that has the file upload. It is unclear whether you are trying to attach one or multiple files to the email. Also, which line shows you the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add an uploaded file as an attachment to an e-mail.

The error message is probably because you are trying to access `$this->pdf['pdf']`, which fails because `$this->pdf` is not an array. I suggest the following improvements:

To retrieve the uploaded file (in `MailController.php`):

```
$pdf = $get->file('attachment');
```

To add the file as an attachment (in `SendEmail.php`)

```
->attach($this->pdf->path(),
    [
        'as' => $this->pdf->getClientOriginalName(),
        'mime' => $this->pdf->getClientMimeType(),
    ]);
```

Here you can find more info (in the Laravel Documentation) about [retrieving an uploaded file](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) and [adding e-mail attachments](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#attachments).

Comment: Hey @nidaime-kakashi, did my answer help you solve the problem? If so, would you please mark it as 'accepted'?